# Why NtOpenSection return error number 0xc0000024?

Tags: c, reverse-engineering

I want to call NtOpensection but return 0xc0000024 error

```
UNICODE_STRING ObFileName;
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES objA;
HANDLE hSectionHandle = NULL;

RtlInitUnicodeString(&ObFileName, L"\\??\\E:\\Myfile.dat");
InitializeObjectAttributes(&objA, &ObFileName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, (HANDLE)NULL, (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)NULL);
NTSTATUS ntStatus = _NtOpenSection(&hSectionHandle, SECTION_MAP_READ | SECTION_MAP_WRITE, &objA);
```

Comment: Is it C or C++? It can't be both!

Comment: Wrong object type.  That string does not exactly look like a valid section object name, my crystal ball says that you meant to use NtCreateSection().

Answer (score 0):

As for **what** the error means, you can check that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx):

```
|===============================|=====================================================|
| 0xC0000024                    | {Wrong Type} There is a mismatch between the type   |
| STATUS_OBJECT_TYPE_MISMATCH   | of object that is required by the requested         |
|                               | operation and the type of object that               |
|                               | is specified in the request.                        |
|===============================|=====================================================|
```

As for **why** it happens, that's for you to determine. Make sure `"\\??\\E:\\Myfile.dat"` is a valid name for a valid section object.

Comment: How sure "\\??\\E:\\Myfile.dat" is a valid name for a valid section object?